# How can I reduce the the font size of algorithm title and index number?

Tags: beamer, algorithms, algorithmic

I write some pseudo codes in Algorithm environment, how can I reduce the font size of algorithm's title and Index number?

```
\begin{frame}{Proposal Algorithm}
\begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
\centering{\textcolor{red}{Proposal}}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \begin{algorithmic}[10]
    \tiny{
        \STATE  a
        \WHILE {\textcolor{red}{$x>0$}}
         \STATE Simulate $g\sim uniformm[0,1]$;\\
         \STATE Simulate $y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$\\
        \ENDWHILE
        }
    \end{algorithmic}
    \caption{\small{$\Delta$- proposla new algorithm}}
    \label{al122}
\end{algorithm}
 \end{minipage}
 \end{frame}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `caption` package to change the font size:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{font=tiny}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Proposal Algorithm}
\begin{minipage}{.49\textwidth}
\centering{\textcolor{red}{Proposal}}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \begin{algorithmic}[10]
    \tiny
        \STATE  a
        \WHILE {\textcolor{red}{$x>0$}}
         \STATE Simulate $g\sim uniformm[0,1]$;\\
         \STATE Simulate $y\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$\\
        \ENDWHILE
    \end{algorithmic}
    \caption{$\Delta$- proposla new algorithm}
    \label{al122}
\end{algorithm}
 \end{minipage}
 \end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]